# C2065 's' undeclared identifier

Tags: c++

im asking for help resolving an error :(
my line of code is as follows

```
// folder name
    std::string folder = "logs";
    CreateDirectoryA(folder.c_str(), nullptr);
    // time format
    auto t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::ostringstream timefmt;
    timefmt << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S");
    // filename
    std::string filename = folder + "\\"s + "client_"s + std::to_string(CLIENT_GET_VERSION()) + "_"s + timefmt.str() + ".dmp"; /* HERE IS MY PROBLEM */

    auto hFile = CreateFileA(filename.c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your `"client_"s` raises the issue. Make sure you've used `#include <string>` and `using std::string_literals::operator""s`.

Comment: it doesnt seem to read my string include,  thanks for help :)

Comment: You don't really need to use `std::string` literals in this code.  Good old-fashioned quoted strings should work just fine (provided that `folder` is a `std::string`).

Answer (score 2):

try to add

```cpp
using namespace std::literals
```